# Implicit Broadcasts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

"Apps that target Android O can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest."

ACTION_VIEW is an implicit broadcast.

According to the above statement, one can no longer register as a broadcast receiver for any URI in the manifest.  The only way to listen for a URI at this point is if the app is already running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ACTION_VIEW is an implicit broadcast.

Not typically. `ACTION_VIEW` is used to start an activity, not as a broadcast `Intent` action.

> one can no longer register as a broadcast receiver for any URI in the manifest

Broadcast receivers rarely filter on a `Uri` (i.e., have `<data>` elements in their `<intent-filter>`).

Comment: You are correct, I was confusing broadcast receivers with intent-filters.

Comment: I'm also very confused about this statement. Does this mean that I have to use `registerReceiver(...)` for almost all broadcasts? What about `wifi.STATE_CHANG` and `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`? I could not get theses broadcasts if I only register them in my manifest?

Comment: @Cilenco: Sorry, but I do not know what you mean by that.

Comment: The statement says that we can not use `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` or `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED ` if we register these broadcasts only in the manifest. [Here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#broadcasts) is pointed out that we can consume `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` with a `JobScheduler` but I'm wondering how I get notified if the device is disconnected from a power source on Android O. Any ideas to that?

Comment: @Cilenco: If you have a process running for other reasons, you can register for that broadcast in the manifest. Otherwise, [hope that they add it to the whitelist](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36734087). `JobScheduler` on its own is useless here.