# Android O activity stack gets reset

Tags: android, activity-stack

First of all I want to say that I am not sure that this is Android O issue, but I have only seen it on an Android O device.

My app has various activities in the stack and the top-most activity is started with LaunchMode: singleTop. This activity starts a different app, which starts the browser (eg. chrome app), which in the end returns to my activity.

my app with Activity X => another app => chrome app => my app with Activity X

Everything went ok until a while ago when I saw that somehow my activity stack gets cleared on a device with Android O, when the user comes back to my app. I think that my task (app) gets removed when the user gets to the browser.

I have checked on some other phone with Android 5.1.1 and it works as expected. The second app has the same version on both phones.

My question is: How can I stop the clear of my activity stack? Is this a change in Android O?

Comment: You could inspect the Activity stack at runtime with `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` on each device and see if that gives you some clues as to what is happening.

Comment: Post your manifest and activity flags if you are using, we need to check it out to figure whats happening in stack.

Comment: @EmreAktürk my activity is started like this:

var intent = new Intent (this, typeof (PaymentActivity));
StartActivityForResult (intent, PAYMENT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

I am using Xamarin so my manifest is mostly generated, but the only setting on the activity is     android:launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: Got it, so in Android O version, when you press back button in chrome it does not return your activity x right?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html 

Please check it out this singleTop explaination. I am still not sure if its excepted behaivor or not.

Comment: @EmreAktürk this is the behaviour I wanted and it worked like this for a long while. I got this issue only now with Android O.  I tried to see what happens when I press back in chrome => it returns to the other app and when I press back again it quits the other app and goes to home screen. I also tried to go back to my app through the "Opened apps", but then it starts my app as if its opened the first time

Comment: Maybe we need to check "Do not keep activities" is disabled in phone settings.

Comment: @EmreAktürk I checked "Do not keep activities" and it is disabled. In the meantime I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959222/implicit-broadcasts)  Could this be it? I am starting the second app with an URI intent with ActionView. When chrome comes back to my app it also comes back with an URI intent with ActionView